# xamarin screen design from code behind

Tags: xamarin, code-behind

I am new to xamarin.i am trying to create accordian control in xamarin forms.i had created also.in which at starting level i had put only buttons and label like this

[image]

for demo purpose.this is i binded from code behind.like this

```
 var vViewLayout1 = new StackLayout()
        {
            Children = {
                new Label { Text = "Regular Board Meeting",HorizontalOptions=LayoutOptions.Center },

                 new StackLayout
                {
                     Spacing = 5,
                     Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                     VerticalOptions= LayoutOptions.Center,
                     HorizontalOptions= LayoutOptions.End,

                      Children =
                         {
                            new Image { Source = "Chat.png"},
                            new Button { Text ="Reject",BackgroundColor = Color.Red,TextColor = Color.White},
                            new Button { Text ="Approve",BackgroundColor = Color.Green,TextColor = Color.White}
                         }
                },
                //new Label { Text = "Name : S Ravi Kumar" },
                //new Label { Text = "Roles : Father,Trainer,Consultant,Architect" }
            }
        };
 var vFirstAccord = new AccordionSource()
        {
            HeaderText = "ReportToBoardJune 1,2016",
            HeaderTextColor = Color.White,
            HeaderBackGroundColor = Color.Red,
            ContentItems = vViewLayout1
        };

 return vResult;
```

but i want to display data such like this
[image]

so ,how can i create this from code behind.and which control i should use for box that i highlighed by red arrow.boxview or any other availble in xamarine like table or anything else.

i just started xamarin.so i dont have any idea about its controls.any suggestion or help is apriciated.thanks in advance.

Comment: I think a [Grid](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Grid/) would fit your needs for the box you highlighted. You can configure a 3x3 grid with even sized cells, and add your labels where they need to go. That API doc includes an example of using the Grid from code behind.

Comment: yeah.. i used. grid.but how can make border around it from code behind?

Comment: i cant find border property of grid

Comment: Xamarin.Forms tends to have very limited properties in each view. You can either add the property yourself, using custom renderers or a custom control, or you can put the `Grid` inside of a `ContentView` and set the `BackgroundColor` and `Padding` properties to get the desired result.

Comment: @Dylan: Thankx a lot for your suggestion and help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments you're going to use grid, and your question is now essentially How can I make a border round the grid in the code behind file?

There is no specific border property for grid as you've discovered. What I've done a few times is create a simple 3x3 grid, and placed 4 boxviews around the edges:

```
BoxView border()
{ 
    BoxView res = new BoxView
    {
        Color = Color.Black,
        HeightRequest = 4,
        WidthRequest = 4
    }
    return res;
}

Grid gridWithBorder = new Grid
{
    RowDefinitions =
        {
            new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto},
            new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto},
            new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto}
        },
   ColumnDefinitions =
        {
            new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Auto },
            new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Auto },
            new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Auto }
        }
};

gridWithBorder.Children.Add(border(), 0, 3, 0, 1);   //add top border
gridWithBorder.Children.Add(border(), 0, 1, 0, 3);   // left border
gridWithBorder.Children.Add(border(), 0, 3, 2, 3);   // bottom border
gridWithBorder.Children.Add(border(), 2, 3, 0, 3);   // right
```

After this I then add the rest of the layout to row 1 column 1

Comment: soory i dont understand your stucture.can you exaplin in brief.?

Comment: should i take 2 extra rowdefination and columndefination in my grid stucture and there should i put boxview?

Comment: @NeelamPrajapati Yes, the two extra columns and rows created get taken up by the boxviews.
In the lines "gridWithBorder.Children.Add" it's specifying what view you're adding, what column, row, and how many colums or rows it is spanning.

Comment: gridWithBorder.Children.Add(border(), 0, 3, 0, 1);   //add top border in this 0 is row  3 is column..thts right.but what is 0 and 1 after that?

Comment: Children.Add(border() // this is the view
, 0 // this is the column
, 3 // this is the amount of columns the view is to span (i.e. columns 0, 1 and 2)
, 0 // this is the row
, 1); // this is the amount of rows the view is to span